# iOS: How to copy pixels from a source to a destination rect?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, core-graphics

programmers! Is there a way to copy bitmap-data from one region of the display to another (like bitblt in Windows)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to the iPhone display, but you can access any views or images your app is displaying.

You can create a subimage from any rectangle in a non-composited view, and then draw that subimage somewhere else (in the same view, or in another) in, say, a drawRect callback.  You can also get at the raw pixel data by getting a pointer to the CGBitmapContext backing a UIView.